# Octave - Variable point symbol in plot

Tags: octave

I'm plotting two vectors against one another.  I would like to vary the symbol used to plot each point based on the corresponding value in a third vector.

In other words, if I'm plotting X and Y, I know I can make each plot point display as '*' like so:

```
plot (X, Y, "*")
```

But how can I involve a third vector Z such that '*' is displayed for some values of Z, and '+' is displayed for others?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little more?  Do you want to change the point style for the i-th point of Y (plotted against X) based on what the i-th element of Z is?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.  I basically want my point style to be a third dimension on my two dimensional plot, capable of showing two different values.  In other words, the point location is defined by X(i) and Y(i), while point style is a function of Z(i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
x = [1 2 3];
y = [1 4 9];
z = {'*' '+' '*'};
for i_=1:length(x)
    eval(["plot(x(" num2str(i_) "),y(" num2str(i_) "),'" z{i_} "')"])
    hold on
end
```

This essentially makes `n` plots, where `n` is the length of `x` and `y`. If you want the point color to change for each point you can use `hold all` instead of `hold on`.  If you want the point style to be conditional on the value of `y`, you can do

```
x = [1 2 3];
y = [1 4 9];
z = {'*' '+' '*'};
for i_=1:length(x)
    if (y(i_) > 1)
        z{i_} = '*';
    else
        z{i_} = '+';
    end
    eval(["plot(x(" num2str(i_) "),y(" num2str(i_) "),'" z{i_} "')"])
    hold on
end
```

Comment: I was really thinking more along the lines of Z being a numerical vector of length 'n' in an of itself.  The value of the point style (either * or +) for a particular point 'i' would be a function of Z(i).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well what you want.  It seems like my second code example could be adapted such that the point style is dependent on the numerical value of Z.  Perhaps you could write a pseudocode example showing what you want?

Comment: You're right.  Now that I look at it, I think your answer can be adapted for my purposes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Can also be done by getting the indices of elements of Z for which **+/*** are to printed in 2 separate arrays using `find` method.

Considering that you want to print **(+)** for *positive* values of Z and **(*)** for *negative* values, the following code will do it:

```
    pos = find(Z > 0); neg = find(Z <= 0);
    plot(X(pos), Y(pos), 'k+', X(neg), Y(neg), 'k*');
```

Comment: This answer is better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

code below will print 'ro' for z > 0 and 'bx' for z < 0

```
plot(x(z>0), y(z>0), 'ro', x(z<0), y(z<0), 'bx')
```